# Difference between azimuth degrees when i use st_project in postgis

Tags: postgis-2.0

[image: difference degrees]

I have two points p1 and p2.

```
 SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(92.78488163381019 55.9757874622428)',  4326) as p1,
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT(92.78482645521103 55.97564239375992)', 4326) as p2
```

**degree** between points equal 200.824
and **distance** between points equal 16.492

```
SELECT degrees(ST_Azimuth(p1, p2)) as degree,
       ST_Distance_Sphere(p1, p2)  as distance</code></pre>
```

But i have different degree when i use st_Project with this arguments:

```
SELECT degrees(ST_Azimuth(p1, _p2)),
       ST_Distance_Sphere(p1, p2)
FROM (
  SELECT (ST_Project(p1, distance, radians(degree))::geometry as _p2 FROM ...
)
```

It returns:

```
  st_distance_sphere  ||       degrees
======================||====================
  16.4661410575154    ||  214.150581571718
```

Distance difference between (p1,p2) and (p1,_p2) changing only by 0.02 meter. But degree changing by 13 degrees.

Why degrees are not equal between other?

Comment: Tell us what p1 and p2 are, so we can actually duplicate your result. Also tell us postgis_full_version().

Comment: Sorry, add coordinates to question.

Postgis_full_version: "POSTGIS="2.0.3 r11128" GEOS="3.3.8-CAPI-1.7.8" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.0, released 2011/12/29" LIBXML="2.9.0" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" RASTER"

Comment: I apply this code for other points: (0,0) and (90,90) and get same wrong [result](http://pastie.org/8422866).

Comment: No answer yet, but I'm willing to guess this is mixing up of units/geography/geometry types.

Comment: You right! I cast coordinates from geography to geometry type. And instead ST_Project use ST_Translate( p1, sin(radians(degree))*distance1, cos(radians(degree))*distance1)

Comment: @PaulRamsey on the same note, I think there are problems with `ST_DistanceSphere` where PostGIS casts geometry->geography https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/191277/2639 Love for you to look at that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's my fault. Like Paul Ramsey said - i use mixing types geography and geometry at the same time.

To resolve this i transform all points to geometry (with srid 3576) and instead ST_Project use
    ST_Translate( p1, sin(radians(degree))*distance1, cos(radians(degree))*distance1)

My final code is:

```
SELECT distance1,
       ST_Distance( p1, _p2) as distance2
       degree1,
       degrees(ST_Azimuth( p1, _p2)) as degree2
FROM 
(SELECT p1, p2, distance1, degree1, ST_Translate( p1, sin(radians(degree1))*distance1, cos(radians(degree1))*distance1) as _p2 FROM
  (SELECT p1, p2, ST_Distance(p1, p2) as distance1, degrees(ST_Azimuth(p1, p2)) as degree1 FROM
    (SELECT ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(92.78488163381019 55.9757874622428)', 4326), 3576) as p1, ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(92.78482645521103 55.97564239375992)', 4326),3576) as p2
    ) as points
  ) as foo
) as bar
```

Result: distance1 == distance2 and degree1 == degree2